# Is it possible to create a popup window in Openlayers2.12 without setting any coordinates on it?

Tags: openlayers-2, popup

I use Openlayers 2.12 and create a popup window like this:

```
popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
              new OpenLayers.LonLat(latlotArr[0],latlotArr[1]).transform( fromProjection, toProjection),
              new OpenLayers.Size(300, 300),htmlImg,null, true);
```

I get the coordinates from some images. But some of the images don't have any coords. In this case I just want to display the popup without a specific location.

How can I do that? I tried this:

```
popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
                     new OpenLayers.LonLat(null,null),
                     new OpenLayers.Size(300, 300),
                     htmlImg,
                     null, true);
```

But ofcource it didn't work. I get an error: invalid value for variable lat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you look at the [source code](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Popup.js#L330) for OpenLayers.Popup, from which all other popup types are derived, you will see on line 333 that the position of the div is determined by converting the passed in lat/lon to a pixel location. If you do not have a lat/lon for an image, you could always pass in your map's centre point, or top left, whatever, in it's place. The other option would be to override the draw function, setting the px to some pixel location your choose, rather than deriving it from a geographical position.

Comment: Thanks. I actually did what you suggested. I used the map centre.